# Difference between starch surfactant and CTAB, SDS, Tx-100

Tags: physical-chemistry, nanotechnology, environmental-chemistry, surfactants

I am doing a research on the effect of surfactant on ZnO nanoparticles properties. There is a confusion here between starch surfactant and CTAB, Tx-100 and SDS. I need point on what is the difference between these surfactants in terms of their costs and effects on environment.